# Hydrolysis of phosphoryl-oximes

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, proteins, enzymes, pharmacology

When acetylcholinesterase that has been inhibited by an organophosphorus compound is reactivated by an oxime, a phosphoryl-oxime is formed, which is then somehow hydrolyzed in the blood.
One study suggested that enzymes of the paraoxonase family are responsible [1], while another suggested that this may not be so [2].
What is/are the pathway(s) by which phosphoryl oximes are hydrolyzed?

**References:**

[1] Luo, C., Saxena, A., Smith, M., Garcia, G., Radić, Z., Taylor, P., & Doctor, B. P. (1999). Phosphoryl Oxime Inhibition of Acetylcholinesterase during Oxime Reactivation Is Prevented by Edrophonium. Biochemistry, 38(31), 9937–9947. doi:10.1021/bi9905720

[2] Kiderlen, D., Worek, F., Klimmek, R., & Eyer, P. (2000). The phosphoryl oxime-destroying activity of human plasma. Archives of Toxicology, 74(1), 27–32. doi:10.1007/s002040050648